# How to know target device in WiFi direct?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect to my device from another device and send a simple string via wifi direct.
I was able to get the list of peers available however how do I know that this is my device that I need to send the info to?

Answer (score 0):

The documention at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html outlines this scenerio.

> With peer discovery using discoverPeers(WifiP2pManager.Channel, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener), an application discovers the neighboring peers, but has no good way to figure out which peer to establish a connection with. For example, if a game application is interested in finding all the neighboring peers that are also running the same game, it has no way to find out until after the connection is setup. Pre-association service discovery is meant to address this issue of filtering the peers based on the running services.

Try using addLocalService(), so you peer devices can discover your "simple string" p2p service.